# Creating a complete new column from random values in R

Tags: r, random, data.table, aggregate, multiple-columns

New R user here and I'm looking to create a new column with randomly selected data from the existing columns.  I have a table of data for five years but with random cells missing data across different years. I would like to create a new column which is full with data, randomly chosen from any points across the five years.

The dataset is huge, but it resembles something like:

| Individual | size 2010 | weight 2010 | gender 2010 | size 2011 | weight 2011 | gender 2011 | size 2012 | weight 2012 | gender 2012 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 100 | 50 | M | 100 | 55 | M | 101 | 65 | M |
| B | 75 | NA | F | 75 | NA | F | 75 | 60 | F |
| C | 90 | 65 | F | 90 | 67 | F | NA | 70 | F |
| D | NA | 70 | NA | NA | 50 | M | NA | 55 | NA |
| E | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | 120 | 70 | M |

Eventually, I would like a column added after this data, which reads 'size', 'weight', and 'gender' with a random variable chosen from any of the years in the table.

Comment: So you want to randomly choose a row of size, weight, gender? You should first create these columns and separate columns for each year. Sampling and replacing is easier then ie go from wide to long first.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way how we could do it:

Note here we exclude NA for sampling and values are randomly taken from all years of size, therefore we first make a long format.

If you want to leave randomly NA. Ten change

`apply(df1[3:5], 2, function(x){sample(x[!is.na(x)], size = nrow(df)})`

with

`apply(df1, 2, sample, size = nrow(df))`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# 1.  get long format
df1 <- df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -Individual, 
                    names_to = c('.value', 'year'), 
                    names_pattern = '(.*)\\.(\\d+)')

# 2. sample excluding NA
df2 <- apply(df1[3:5], 2, function(x){sample(x[!is.na(x)], size = nrow(df)})

# 3. cbind both
data.frame(df2) %>% 
  cbind(df)

# end

## Variation: combining the last two (2. and 3.) steps and including NA in sample:

cbind(df, data.frame(apply(df1[3:5], 2, sample, size = nrow(df))))
```

```
  size weight gender Individual size.2010 weight.2010 gender.2010 size.2011 weight.2011 gender.2011 size.2012
1   90     70      F          A       100          50           M       100          55           M       101
2   75     50      F          B        75          NA           F        75          NA           F        75
3  101     67      M          C        90          65           F        90          67           F        NA
4  100     60      F          D        NA          70        <NA>        NA          50           M        NA
5  120     55      M          E        NA          NA        <NA>        NA          NA        <NA>       120
  weight.2012 gender.2012
1          65           M
2          60           F
3          70           F
4          55        <NA>
5          70           M
```

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer!  Also, the cbind is useful for other commands that I have been trying to create in the script, and I will adopt this usage too.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `data.table` solution. I assume you want non-`NA` data where available, so I'm using `na.omit(.)[1]`; if you want `NA`s included in the candidate values, then remove the first line of the function internal to `fun`'s `sapply`.

```r
library(data.table)
fun <- function(...)
  sapply(data.table::transpose(list(...)), 
         function(R) { 
           if (any(!is.na(R))) R <- na.omit(R)
           R[sample.int(length(R), size = 1)]
         })

set.seed(42)
nms <- c("size", "gender", "weight")
for (nm in nms) dat[, paste0(nm, "_random") := do.call(fun, .SD), .SDcols = patterns(paste0("^", nm))]

dat[]
#    Individual size.2010 weight.2010 gender.2010 size.2011 weight.2011 gender.2011 size.2012 weight.2012 gender.2012 size_random gender_random weight_random
#        <char>     <int>       <int>      <char>     <int>       <int>      <char>     <int>       <int>      <char>       <int>        <char>         <int>
# 1:          A       100          50           M       100          55           M       101          65           M         100             M            65
# 2:          B        75          NA           F        75          NA           F        75          60           F          75             F            60
# 3:          C        90          65           F        90          67           F        NA          70           F          90             F            65
# 4:          D        NA          70        <NA>        NA          50           M        NA          55        <NA>          NA             M            70
# 5:          E        NA          NA        <NA>        NA          NA        <NA>       120          70           M         120             M            70
```

Comment: This is very helpful and it seems to work on my dataset.  I will try building it into a function for my larger dataset now, and I appreciate the help!