# Mutate new column from random value in existing columns

Tags: r, random, data.table, aggregate, sample

I'm looking to mutate my data and create a new column which randomly selects a value from the existing data.  My data looks something like:

| individual | age_2010 | age_2011 | age_2012 | age_2013 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 20 | 21 | NA | 21 |
| b | 33 | 34 | 35 | 36 |
| c | 76 | NA | 78 | 79 |
| d | 46 | 46 | 48 | 49 |

And I want it to look like:

| individual | age_2010 | age_2011 | age_2012 | age_2013 | Random Sample |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 20 | 21 | 22 | NA | 21 |
| b | 33 | 34 | 35 | 36 | 36 |
| c | 76 | NA | 78 | 79 | 78 |
| d | 46 | 46 | 48 | 49 | 48 |

Is there any way to add a new column which includes a random figure from any of the previous age columns, and preferably keeping the data in wide form?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a complete new column from random values in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73113847/creating-a-complete-new-column-from-random-values-in-r) (specifically my [recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73128710/3358272) there).

Answer (score 2):

I think this is an easier approach:

```
d[, RandomSample:=sample(na.omit(t(.SD)),1),individual]
```

If dealing with the edge cases discussed above is desired, and one wanted to follow this approach, we could do this:

```
f <- function(df) {
  s = na.omit(t(df))
  ifelse(length(s)>0, sample(s,1),NA_real_)
}
d[, RandomSample:=f(.SD),individual]
```

Or,
we could just wrap the original approach in `tryCatch`

```
d[, RandomSample:=tryCatch(sample(na.omit(t(.SD)),1),error=\(e) NA),individual]
```

Comment: very nice, this is definitely better than my solution

Answer (score 1):

You can reshape longer, then do grouped sampling:

```r
library(data.table)

# Sample data
d <- structure(list(individual = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), age_2010 = c(20, 33, 76, 46), age_2011 = c(21, 34, NA, 46), age_2012 = c(NA, 35, 78, 48), age_2013 = c(21, 36, 79, 49)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(individual = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", "collector")), age_2010 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector")), age_2011 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector")), age_2012 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector")), age_2013 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", "collector")), skip = 2L), class = "col_spec"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
d
#>    individual age_2010 age_2011 age_2012 age_2013
#> 1:          a       20       21       NA       21
#> 2:          b       33       34       35       36
#> 3:          c       76       NA       78       79
#> 4:          d       46       46       48       49

# Solution
d[, "Random Sample"] <- d |> 
    melt("individual") |> # go long
    (`[`)(!is.na(value), # drop NAs
          .(x = sample(value, 1)), # sampling
          keyby = .(individual)) |> # Grouping variable
    (`[[`)(2) # extract vector from frame
d
#>    individual age_2010 age_2011 age_2012 age_2013 Random Sample
#> 1:          a       20       21       NA       21            21
#> 2:          b       33       34       35       36            33
#> 3:          c       76       NA       78       79            76
#> 4:          d       46       46       48       49            49
```

Alternatively, you can also use `apply()`, which is less verbose but much slower:

```r
d[, "Random Sample"] <- apply(d[, -1], 1, \(x) x |> na.omit() |> sample(1))
```

See the benchmark here for speed comparison. On just 40k observations, `apply()` needs 59 times longer and 8 times the memory.

```r
# Make large sample data set
d_large <- d |> 
  list() |> 
  rep(1e4) |> 
  rbindlist()

bench::mark(
  base = apply(d_large[, -1], 1, \(x) x |> na.omit() |> sample(1)),
  dt = d_large |> 
    melt("individual") |> 
    (`[`)(!is.na(value), 
          .(x = sample(value, 1)), 
          keyby = .(individual)) |> 
    (`[[`)(2),
  check = F
)
#> Warning: Some expressions had a GC in every iteration; so filtering is disabled.
#> # A tibble: 2 × 6
#>   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 base       617.86ms  617.9ms      1.62   103.3MB     12.9
#> 2 dt           6.96ms   10.5ms     80.9     13.1MB     47.3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

### Edit:

Here are versions that work with the edge case where all years are `NA`. In the first case I went for a join with the original table, which is a bit more expensive than the other version

```
# Solution with Data Table
d <- d |> 
    melt("individual") |> # go long
    (`[`)(!is.na(value), # drop NAs
          .(`Random Sample` = sample(value, 1)), # sampling
          keyby = .(individual)) |> # Grouping variable
    (`[`)(d) #  right join with original frame
```

Here I simply used `purrr::possibly()` to return `NA` when sampling a zero length vector.

```r
# Solution with apply
d[, "Random Sample"] <- apply(d[, -1], 1, 
                              \(x) x |> na.omit() |> purrr::possibly(sample, NA)(1))
```

Comment: From the OP: *"keeping the data in wide form"*

Comment: And the result is in wide form. Not reshaping in the process is tying your hands behind your back in terms of performance. But if OP really wants to, he can go for the `apply()` solution.

Comment: One caveat for the proposed solutions: Both fail if there are individuals which are NA for all years, as `sample()` fails for zero-length inputs

Comment: Your solution works fine, and my first thought was also go do a double-reshape. However, this is the author's *second* (effectively identical) question on this, where the previous question already had [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73114224/3358272) providing what is effectively a double-pivot. (I mostly think this question should be closed as a dupe of that question, we'll see when the author weighs in on the answers.)

Comment: Yes, I only realized after submitting, that basically the same question had been asked by OP and was already answered. Otherwise I would not have bothered. It is quite disrespectful of your time and effort to repost the question without even engaging with the submitted answers for the original question

Comment: It happens every now and then, most often by new users. I often prefer to close the *previous* question, if for no other reason than it keeps the newer (nearly-identical, almost always better-phrased) answer higher on the list of questions. In this case, though, the other question already had two answers (disclaimer: one mine), so I voted to close this one as a dupe of the first one.

Comment: Thanks for the engagement with the question, it hugely helps and is reassuring as I learn the early steps with R.  I meant no disrespect by posting twice, instead I was just looking for multiple answers to try build a better understanding of how to work the data.   
However, for the rows where I have 4 NAs and only one value, the "Random Sample" creates a new figure completely.  In this instance, is there anyway for the "Random Sample" to be a repeat of the single value in the row, while continuing to sample other rows?

Comment: Can you post an example of this? Both the `data.table` code as well as the `apply()` version should give an error when there is a row where all ages are `NA`. This is for different reasons. `apply()` fails, because `sample()` cannot sample from a zero length vector. The `data.table` version fails, because the row will be filtered out altogether and failure occurs when trying to assign a column that is shorter than the number of rows of the data table, as `data.table` does not recycle.